# JavaScript не выдает верный запрос, как правильно написать

Tags: javascript, sql, xpath

есть у меня один пункт в программе где нужно с помощью кода создать правило обработки сообщение, чтобы сообщение пришло по определенным параметрам и пишется он на JavaScript-е а я в нем .... ноль: я конечно немного понимаю определенные значения но....

```
   var ret = false; 
var sqlres = sql.exec("select case when count(*)>0  then 1 else 0 end from incomings where type = 'E' and id=?", event.getNum("//par[@name='inc_id']/text()"); 
if( sqlres.get(0) == "1")
ret = true; 
ret;
```

в данном коде на данный момент выбирается информация о закрытии документа с типом 'E', мне надо чтобы выбиралась информация о закрытии документа с типом 'E' и при этом с несколькими владельцами документа '''owner_id in (18096, 21364, 20386, 21666)''', я пробывал вставлять в  запрос но получается что система отсылает полупустые сообщения если номера не соответствую '''owner_id''' а если соответствуют то отсылают полноценное сообщение.

Comment: ' var ret = false; 
var sqlres = sql.exec("select case when count(*)>0  then 1 else 0 end from incomings where owner_id in (18096, 21364, 20386, 21666) and type = 'E' and id=?", event.getNum("//par[@name='inc_id']/text()"); 
if( sqlres.get(0) == "1")
ret = true; 
ret;  '  - так я пробывал, пустые сообщения если не равен заданному owner_id а мне это не надо

Comment: Немного добавлю уточнённой информации, ''' id=?", event.getNum("//par[@name='inc_id']/text()" ''' - этот элемент кода должен браться из сообщения ''' <event name=”upload_close_incoming” action=”update”>

               <par name=”inc_id” type=”int”>776</par>

</event> '''